# how does the jit compiler work in JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript

how does the jit compiler work in JAVASCRIPT ??? 
when we only have a  1 compilation phase which declares all of our variables and functions (during the creation of the glbal execution context ?o

Answer (score 1):

> ...when we only have a 1 compilation phase which declares all of our variables and functions...

That's where you're going wrong. :-) Modern JavaScript engines don't have a single compilation phase. Instead, they do an initial pass through the code using something really fast, and then for code that gets reused enough to make it worthwhile, they apply an optimizer to rewrite the code in place with faster code.

In Chrome's V8, the first phase used to be a compiler (called Full-codegen) and the second phase (when needed) was an optimizing compiler called Crankshaft, but [they've switched](https://v8project.blogspot.com/2017/05/launching-ignition-and-turbofan.html) to an *interpreter* called Ignition for the first phase that parses the code, generates bytecode, and executes that, and then for code that makes it worthwhile, they apply an optimizing compiler called TurboFan to the bytecode. (See that blog post for the details.) This was originally to minimize the memory impact of one-off setup code, but it turned out that generating bytecode was faster than generating machine code and startup performance was actually improved as well.

Comment: can you recommend a book or a course , coz i  just started and different ressources  got me lost , as far as i know source code ===> parser ====> AST  ====> bytecode ===> compiler / interpreter (jit) , the jit creates global execution context (this + scope chain + declare all the declarations ),  then the executionof GEC  , for every function call the jit compile again  or something like that which results the creation of a new execution context followed by the execution , ;;

Comment: I don't know of a good book or course or similar to point you at. The V8 blog linked above is useful. But you're conflating two things: Parsing/bytecode/machine code generation, and running the code (creating execution contexts, including the global context, etc.). Those are different things. And the JavaScript engine is perfectly capable of completely replacing a function under-the-covers if it decides to optimize it. Unless there's a bug in the engine, there's no way to know that happened in your code.

Comment: thank you so much , i just googled what you told 
 me and i got it know , much appreciation